# How to use Java to implement code to serialize protobuf object in memory?

Tags: java, python-3.x, tensorflow

I want to know how to use Java to do the same thing like this :

```py
exam_input = tf.constant([example_proto.SerializeToString()])
```

I try to do something like this:

```
val result = sparkEnv.spark.read.parquet(inputPath).map(item => {
      val map = new java.util.HashMap[String,Tensor]()
      val tensor = TString.vectorOf(new String(example.toByteArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
      map.put("examples",tensor)
      val score = model.value.call(map).get("score")
      score.toString
    }).rdd
```

However, it is not correct, so what should I do?

update:

@Karl Lessard:

thank u for your answer. but my problem is to due with lots of features, and the model input is seriliazed example, just like this:

```
MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['examples'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1)
        name: input_example_tensor:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['cf_1'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT64
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: ParseExample/ParseExampleV2:0
    outputs['cf_2'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT64
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: ParseExample/ParseExampleV2:1
    outputs['cf_label'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT64
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: ParseExample/ParseExampleV2:2
    outputs['cf_user_id'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT64
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: ParseExample/ParseExampleV2:3
    outputs['score'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: score:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

i wanna to predict the result using serilized example like python

Comment: Do you want to convert `tf.constant([example_proto.SerializeToString()]) ` to Java ?

Comment: yes , i wanna use java to serialize the example proto object into string , the do some predict

Comment: Are you using Spark ? Which framework ? You have a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71377337/how-to-translate-this-python-tensorflow-2-7-code-into-java). It is a duplicate ?

Comment: yes , i'm using spark . i wanna load model ,and predict the serilized example data one by one , in a map operaion by spark.

Comment: the model input is Example object , but i don't know how to feed a Example object into the loaded model

Comment: maybe some thing like this: https://groups.google.com/g/protobuf/c/e3Z-dCk5ZUo

Comment: The second code snippet is not Java, so what language are you actually using.

Comment: scala , but i think almost the same with java. i use spark to offline predict, using java do online predict

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways for doing this but I think in your case you first want to parse your example proto file to extract the features to be passed as tensors to your function.

A starting point for parsing is the set of protos available in [TFJava](https://github.com/tensorflow/java/tree/master/tensorflow-core/tensorflow-core-api/src/gen/java/org/tensorflow/proto/example). Once you get hold on a list of values (such as a `FloatList`), you can create a tensor from it or by passing that list as an array of bytes to this [factory](https://github.com/tensorflow/java/blob/a4e79643fd734033e000ecd6b9b0c4644440ce7e/tensorflow-core/tensorflow-core-api/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/Tensor.java#L184).

For example this converts the Int64List `input` feature to a vector:

```java
    Example example = Example.parseFrom(new FileInputStream("your_example.pb"));
    Feature feature = example.getFeatures().getFeatureOrThrow("input");
    long[] values = feature.getInt64List().getValueList().stream().mapToLong(i -> i.longValue()).toArray();
    try (TInt64 tensor = TInt64.vectorOf(values)) {
      System.out.println("Tensor shape is " + tensor.shape());
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63421332/what-is-the-tensorflow-java-api-for-tf-train-example-serializetostring-in-python. this is the same question